# Why does importing SparkSession in spark-shell fail with "object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql"?

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera-cdh, apache-spark-1.6

I use Spark 1.6.0 on my VM, Cloudera machine.

I'm trying to enter some data into Hive table from Spark shell.
To do that, I am trying to use SparkSession. But the below import is not working.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
<console>:33: error: object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
         import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

And without that, I cannot execute this statement:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation).config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse").getOrCreate()
<console>:33: error: not found: value SparkSession
         val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition","true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation).config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse").getOrCreate()
```

Can anyone tell me what mistake am I doing here ?

Comment: Well, are you 100% sure you have Spark2?

Comment: Which version of spark do you use? Have you ensured you could open up the spark shell without any errors?

Comment: @PraveenKumarKrishnaiyer There are no errors when I open the spark shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SparkSession` [is available as of Spark 2.0](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/8fc267ab3322e46db81e725a5cb1adb5a71b2b4d) so you should be using `SQLContext` instead (or upgrade your Spark to the latest and greatest [2.1.1](http://spark.apache.org/news/spark-2-1-1-released.html)).

Quoting Spark 1.6.0's [Starting Point: SQLContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sqlcontext):

> The entry point into all functionality in Spark SQL is the `SQLContext` class, or one of its descendants.
>
> In addition to the basic SQLContext, you can also create a HiveContext, which provides a superset of the functionality provided by the basic SQLContext.