# How to import the sparksession

Tags: apache-spark

How can I create the sparksession?

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala>    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext 
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> val conf = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testing").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()  

<console>:27: error: not found: value SparkSession
         val conf = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testing").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does importing SparkSession in spark-shell fail with "object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772397/why-does-importing-sparksession-in-spark-shell-fail-with-object-sparksession-is)

Answer (score 5):

SparkSession is available in spark 2.x

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
```

Though when you start spark shell SparkSession is already available as `spark` variable.

Answer (score 1):

As undefined_variable mentioned, you need to run `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession` to access the `SparkSession` class.

It was also mentioned that you don't need to create your own SparkSession in the Spark console because it's already created for you.

[image]

Notice the "Spark session available as 'spark'" message when the console is started.

You can run this code in the console but it actually doesn't create a new SparkSession:

```scala
val conf = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testing").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

The `getOrCreate` portion tells Spark to use an existing SparkSession if it exists and only create a new SparkSession if necessary.  In this case, the Spark Shell created a SparkSession, so the existing SparkSession will be used.

```scala
conf == spark // true
```

See [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/sparksession/) for more information on how to manage the SparkSession in production applications.

Answer (score 0):

Scala Spark:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val conf = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testing").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder \
 .appName("testing") \
 .enableHiveSupport() \
 .getOrCreate()
```

Add `.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")` before `.getOrCreate()` to set config.

Refer: [Scala Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession), [Python Docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession)